# Why does Parralax scrolling not scroll at all on mobile?

Tags: jquery, ios, css, scroll

I am developing my first parralax website, but for some reason on my iPhone it doesn't scroll at all. It's not a question of animation or not, I just can't scroll anywhere, I am completely locked on the first image.

I'm following this tutorial: https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/

I downloaded the starting files and just created the same site which works great on desktop but does nothing on mobile. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery and Javascript runs at a much slower frame rate on mobile due to the fact it can be very memory heavy. The trouble with this is animations can be slow or just non existent. The Parallax effect is constantly checking on the scroll position of the browser window but as this updates much slower on iPhone it often seems non responsive.

You can still achieve a parallax effect if you are very efficient with your coding but the effect will never be as smooth on desktop.

If you look at many mobile sites you will see they stay away from using too many animation effects on mobile as the general idea is to streamline the site so it can be downloaded quickly.

I know that doesn't help you too much but I hope it gives a bit of insight into the problem.

Comment: Then why does it work on site like this ryanscherf.net?

Comment: Because thats not a parallax effect thats the bit at the top is just has a fixed position and the rest hasn't all that is done with simple CSS.

Comment: How do you set up a page like that where only the top and bottom are fixed? Can you give me some tips as I see a lot of sites like that. @Joe Barbour

Comment: @user3460974 To follow on with your question and using your example I would build the basic structure like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/vjvysmLy/1/